# Как превратить координаты Min0, Min1, Max0, Max1 в Rectangle?

Tags: c#

Есть координаты прямоугольника на экране: `Min0`, `Min1`, `Max0`, `Max1`.
Их нужно превратить в

```
Rectangle(x, y, width, height)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Вычислить ширину и высоту и передать как параметры в конструктор

Comment: `width = Max0 - Min0`, `height = Max1 - Min1`?

Comment: А можно целиком пример, что передавать в конуструктор? new Rectnagle(x, y, width, height);

Comment: первые 2 параметра - минимальные значения, вторые два - ширина и высота. Чуть чуть подумайте и сможете написать код сами